# Python with inconsistent result while printing, wondering what could be the reason?

Tags: python

```
>>> all=[""]

>>> i="One"

>>> l=(item for item in all if item in i)

>>> print(len(list(l)))

1
>>> print(len(list(l)))

0

>>>
```

first time print answer is 1 without any modification second time its 0

Comment: The use of `all` as a variable name overwrites the builtin `all()` function.  Strongly recommend changing the name to something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `l` it an Generator. When it stops iterator (after first time) it is empty and return len of 0.

Use `[item for item in all if item in i]` instead of `(item for item in all if item in i)` for making it a list

Comment: Polite correction: Strictly speaking, `l` is a generator, which is why it’s expired after use.

Comment: @S3DEV Your are right. Iterator is what the Generator return (like index). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

your `l` is a generator. The first time you call it with `list(l)` it gives you a list. The second time you call it, the generator is empty, therefore the length is 0